# Use keyboard media buttons for Spotify, not YouTube

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, mediaplayer

Ever since I updated to macOS 10.14.4,  I've been having trouble with media buttons working with YouTube and not Spotify. Is there anyway to write a script to remove YouTube access or is there a way in system preferences to set Spotify as the default?
Thanks!